# Flask development environment breaks when importing views.py

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, flask

So I have this web app running in a Ubuntu 16.04 VM using Docker Compose, and it has four containers:
Elasticsearch, Node (react fronend), Nginx, Flask (backend)

For Flask, I have to files: **init**.py and views.py

When I run the Flask container in development mode, everything works. If I make a change to any of the files, it reloads properly. The moment I add this line to **init**.py: "import flaskr.views" or anything similar that imports views.py, the reloader breaks. It never reloads, just freezes and crashes.

Flask is the latest version and Python is 3.6.2.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you run it fresh with the `import flaskr.views` line does it still crash or only when being realoaded? Might be a circular import?

Comment: Is this Docker-specific? Or fails outside of Docker as well?